# How can I cast "const void*" to the function pointer in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, constants, function-pointers

I want to convert some `const void*` object into a function pointer:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, const void*> originals_;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
R CallOriginal(const std::string& name, Args... args) {
  return reinterpret_cast<R (*const)(Args...)>(originals_[name])(args...);
}
```

But, to my surprise, I get the following error message:

> error: reinterpret_cast from 'mapped_type' (aka 'const void *') to
>   'int (*const)(int)' casts away qualifiers

First of all, does it even make sense to use the `const` function pointer?
If it does, then how can I legally make the casting?

Comment: Why are you coercing function pointers to `const void*` to store them in the map in the first place? Why don't you just store function pointers?

Comment: Because I want to store pointers to the functions with different signatures. More over, the library that I use to manipulate the function pointers does convert them to `void*` and accept them as `void const*`.

Comment: Interestingly, g++4.9.2 seems to accept this conversion. IIRC, there's also a proposal to remove the restriction that `reinterpret_cast` may not cast away cv-qualifiers.

Comment: That just sounds like a terrible idea. Since function types are known at compile time, there can only be a finite number of them, so you should have a separate map for each type. Don't fight the type system; make it work for you. I never understand why people try to use C++ as though it were a dynamically typed language.

Comment: @Brian The question is not about idea - it's more about syntax and curiosity.  And I don't want the map for each separate signature, I want the map for all function replacements by their names - not to store a sole function pointer in a separate variable, otherwise, that really would be terrible. Also I use the third-party C library, AFAIK casting everything to `void*` in C is not that bad as in C++.

Comment: @dyp I'm using the trunk clang. Looks like it's a compiler specific...

Comment: intel 15.0.2 allows this as well. Of course everything about this conversion is implementation-defined (per `5.2.10[expr.reinterpret.cast]/8`)

Comment: You are trying to invent your own reflection ?

Comment: If you throw away the function's type, how do you know *exactly* what to call it with? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715219/store-functions-with-different-signatures-in-a-map/45718187#45718187

Answer (score 2):

In order to call any function by it's name you can use [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) combined with standard library functor [std::function](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Be aware, caller must know the signature, e.g. parameter types and return type can not be deduced.

An example:

```
#include <any>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <iostream>

static int foo(int a, const std::string& b) {
    std::cout << "foo(" << a << ',' << b << ");" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

static void bar(float a, const std::string& b) {
    std::cout << "bar(" << a << ',' << b << ");" << std::endl;
}

class call_function_by_name {
public:
    explicit call_function_by_name(std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any>&& table):
        table_(table)
    {}
    template <typename R,typename... ArgTypes>
    R call(const std::string& name,ArgTypes... args) const {
       typedef std::function<R(ArgTypes...)> functor_t;
       std::any anyf = table_.at(name);
       // call function by name
       functor_t functor = std::any_cast<functor_t>( anyf ) ;
       return functor( args... );
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any> table_;
};


int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any> exportTable;
    exportTable.emplace("foo", std::function<int(int,const std::string&)>(foo) );
    exportTable.emplace("bar", std::function<void(float,const std::string&)>(bar) );

    call_function_by_name bus( std::move(exportTable) );
    int ret = bus.call<int,int,const std::string&>("foo", 1, std::string("bus foo") );
    std::cout << "Foo returned " << ret << std::endl;
    bus.call<void,float,const std::string&>("bar", 2.0F, "bus bar");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to erase function signature and store just function pointer.

For this you can cast function pointers to other function pointers, like to `typedef void(*p)()`.

C++ can work on an architecture where data memory and code memory do not interact and have different pointer size. So cast function pointer to data pointer is generally not safe